# Rails 5.2 Syntax Error on Simple Update Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a weird `syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting '}' else`   error on a pretty simple rails method in my `votes_controller.rb`:

```
 def update
    if @vote.update(vote_params)
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_applications_path)
      flash[:notice] = "Your vote has been successfully changed."
    else << ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_applications_path)
      flash[:warning] = "Uh oh!  Something went wrong.  Please try again later."
    end
  end
```

Unless I'm missing something incredibly stupid, I feel like this error has to be coming from somewhere else.  My server log doesn't give me any more information than this error message.

The only thing it references is my `vote_params`, which looks like this:

```
  def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(
      :application_type,
      :application_id,
      :user_id,

      :accept,

      :modify,
      :modification,
      :suggest_loan,
      :describe_loan,

      :deny,
      :denial_fund_overuse,
      :denial_not_qualify,
      :denial_unreasonable_request,
      :denial_not_involved_charity,
      :denial_other,
      :denial_other_description,

      :superseded,
      :seconded
    )
  end
```

Has anyone seen an error message like this on something that doesn't seem to merit it?

**ADDITIONAL INFO: WHOLE CONTROLLER**

Apologies for the length...

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_vote, only: [:update, :destroy, :own_vote_only]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_application, only: [:second_vote]
  before_action :own_vote_only, only: [:update, :destroy]
  before_action :committee_only, only: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]



  def set_application
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
    if @vote.application_type == "hardship"
      @application = Hardship.find_by(id: @vote.application_id)
    elsif @vote.application_type == "scholarship"
      @application = Scholarship.find_by(id: @vote.application_id)
    elsif @vote.application_type == "charity"
      @application = Charity.find_by(id: @vote.application_id)
    end
  end



  def create
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
    @vote.user_id = current_user.id

    if Vote.where(user_id: current_user.id, application_type: @vote.application_type, application_id: @vote.application_id).count != 0
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_applications_path)
      flash[:warning] = "Sorry, you can only vote once per application.  If you changed your mind, you can change your existing vote as long as it hasn't been seconded yet."
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @vote.save
          Log.create(category: "Committee Action", action: "Committee Member Voted on an Application", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @vote.application_type, object_id: @vote.application_id, taken_by_user: true, user_id: current_user.id)
          format.html { redirect_to home_applications_path, notice: 'Your vote was successfully cast.  If seconded by another committee member, the application status will be updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vote }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { rend<%= @application.full_name %>er json: @vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end # vote save
      end # respond to format
    end # if vote not duplicate
  end #end method



  def update
    if @vote.update(vote_params)
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_applications_path)
      flash[:notice] = "Your vote has been successfully changed."
    else
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_applications_path)
      flash[:alert] = "Uh oh!  Something went wrong.  Please try again later."
    end
  end



  def destroy
    @vote.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      Log.create(category: "Committee Action", action: "Committee Member Deleted Their Vote on an Application", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @vote.application_type, object_id: @vote.application_id, taken_by_user: true, user_id: current_user.id)
      format.html { redirect_to home_applications_url, notice: 'You have successfully deleted your vote and can now cast another one on this application.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



  def own_vote_only
    unless current_user && ( @vote.user_id == current_user.id )
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_applications_path)
      flash[:warning] = "Sorry, you can only perform that action with your own votes."
    end
  end



  def committee_only
    unless current_user && current_user.committee
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
      flash[:warning] = "Sorry, you must be a committee member to modify an application."
    end
  end



  def second_vote
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])

    if current_user && @vote.user.id == current_user.id
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_pending_path)
      flash[:warning] = "Sorry, you cannot second a vote you submitted!"
    elsif current_user.id == @application.user.id
      redirect_back(fallback_location: home_pending_path)
      flash[:warning] = "Sorry, you cannot second a vote on your own application."
    else
      ## UPDATE VOTE STATUSES
      @other_votes = Vote.where(application_type: @vote.application_type, application_id: @vote.application_id).where.not(id: @vote.id)
      @other_votes.update_all(superseded: true)
      @vote.update_attributes(seconded: true)
      Log.create(category: "Committee Action", action: "A Vote Was Seconded", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @vote.application_type, object_id: @vote.application_id, taken_by_user: true, user_id: current_user.id)

      ## SET APPLICATION
      if @vote.application_type == "hardship"
        @application = Hardship.find_by(id: @vote.application_id)
      elsif @vote.application_type == "scholarship"
        @application = Scholarship.find_by(id: @vote.application_id)
      elsif @vote.application_type == "charity"
        @application = Charity.find_by(id: @vote.application_id)
      end

      ## ACCEPTED APPLICATIONS
      if @vote.accept
        @application.update_attributes(status: "Decision Reached", final_decision: "Approved", approved: true)
        Log.create(category: "Committee Action", action: "An Application Was Approved", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @vote.application_type, object_id: @vote.application_id, taken_by_user: false)

        # FOR OTHER HARDSHIPS
        if @application.application_type == "hardship" && @application.for_other

          # if recipient has TOCA Cares account
          if User.where(email: @application.recipient_toca_email).count != 0

              # Transfer application authorization
              @application.user_id = User.where(email: @application.recipient_toca_email).first.id
              if @application.save
                Log.create(category: "Automatic", action: "Hardship Application Transferred from Submitter to Beneficiary", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              # Hardship transfer email to beneficiary
              if HardshipMailer.hardship_transferred_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Hardship Transfer Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              # hardship accepted email to helping hands
              if HardshipMailer.approved_hardship_to_helping_hands_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Accepted Hardship Application Sent to Helping Hands", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              # hardship accepted email to beneficiary
              if HardshipMailer.by_other_hardship_accepted_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Automatic", action: "Hardship Application Accepted Email sent to Submitting User", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: "hardship", object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

          # recipient doesn't have TOCA Cares account
          else

              # transfer authorization created
              if @application.update_attributes(transfer_pending: true)
                Log.create(category: "Automatic", action: "Preemptive Transfer Authorization Created for Approved Hardship Application Created by Other", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              # create a new account email
              if AccountActionsMailer.create_an_account_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Create an Account Invitation Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              ###NOTE: email notifications to beneficiary, submitter, & helping hands called once user creates account, in RegistrationsController
          end

          # hardship accepted email to SUBMITTING member
          if HardshipMailer.for_other_hardship_accepted_email(@application).deliver
            Log.create(category: "Email", action: "For Other Hardship Application Accepted Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
          end


        # ALL SELF-SUBMITTED APPLICATIONS
        else
          if @vote.application_type == "hardship"
            if HardshipMailer.hardship_accepted_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Hardship Application Accepted Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
            if HardshipMailer.approved_hardship_to_helping_hands_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Accepted Hardship Application Sent to Helping Hands", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          elsif @vote.application_type == "scholarship"
            if ScholarshipMailer.scholarship_accepted_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Scholarship Application Accepted Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
            if ScholarshipMailer.approved_scholarship_to_helping_hands_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Accepted Scholarship Application Sent to Helping Hands", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          elsif @vote.application_type == "charity"
            if CharityMailer.charity_accepted_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Charity Application Accepted Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
            if CharityMailer.approved_charity_to_helping_hands_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Accepted Charity Application Sent to Helping Hands", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          end
        end

      ## MODIFIED APPLICATIONS
      elsif @vote.modify
        @application.update_attributes(status: "Returned for Modifications", final_decision: "Modifications Requested", returned: true)
        Log.create(category: "Committee Action", action: "An Application Was Returned for Modifications", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @vote.application_type, object_id: @vote.application_id, taken_by_user: false)

        # FOR OTHER HARDSHIPS
        if @application.application_type == "hardship" && @application.for_other

          # if user has a TOCA Cares account already
          if User.where(email: @application.recipient_toca_email).count != 0

              # application transfer
              @application.user_id = User.where(email: @application.recipient_toca_email).first.id
              if @application.save
                Log.create(category: "Automatic", action: "Hardship Application Transferred from Submitter to Beneficiary", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              # hardship transferred email to submitting member
              if HardshipMailer.hardship_transferred_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Hardship Transferred Email Sent to Submitter", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end

              # notification to submitter (not beneficiary)
              if AccountActionsMailer.for_other_hardship_modified_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Email", action: "For Other Hardship Application Modified Email Sent to Submitting User", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end


          # if user has to make a TOCA Cares Account
          else
              #transfer authorization created
              if @application.update_attributes(transfer_pending: true)
                Log.create(category: "Automatic", action: "Preemptive Transfer Authorization Created for Modifications Requested Hardship Application Created by Other", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end
              # create an account email sent to beneficiary
              if AccountActionsMailer.create_an_account_email(@application).deliver
                Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Create an Account Invitation Email Sent to Hardship Beneficiary", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
              end
          end


        # ALL SELF-SUBMITTED APPLICATIONS
        else
          if @vote.application_type == "hardship"
            if HardshipMailer.hardship_modification_request_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Hardship Application Needs Modifications Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          elsif @vote.application_type == "scholarship"
            if ScholarshipMailer.scholarship_modification_request_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Scholarship Application Needs Modifications Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          elsif @vote.application_type == "charity"
            if CharityMailer.charity_modification_request_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Charity Application Needs Modifications Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          end
        end

      ## DENIED APPLICATIONS
      elsif @vote.deny
        if @application.update_attributes(status: "Decision Reached", final_decision: "Rejected", denied: true)
          Log.create(category: "Committee Action", action: "An Application Was Denied", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @vote.application_type, object_id: @vote.application_id, taken_by_user: false)
        end

        # if for other person
        if @application.application_type == "hardship" && @application.for_other

          #send rejection email to submitting member
          if AccountActionsMailer.for_other_hardship_denied_email(@application).deliver
            Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Hardship Application (Submitted for Other) Denied Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
          end

        else # not for others

          if @vote.application_type == "hardship"
            if HardshipMailer.hardship_denied_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Hardship Application Denied Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          elsif @vote.application_type == "scholarship"
            if ScholarshipMailer.scholarship_denied_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Scholarship Application Denied Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          elsif @vote.application_type == "charity"
            if CharityMailer.charity_denied_email(@application).deliver
              Log.create(category: "Email", action: "Charity Application Denied Email Sent", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: @application.application_type, object_id: @application.id, taken_by_user: false)
            end
          end

        end # application for self or others if/else
      end #end vote statuses (accept/modify/deny)

      redirect_to home_applications_path
      flash[:notice] = "That vote has been successfully seconded and the application is being processed accordingly. Thank you for serving on the deciding committee!" # if current user isn't vote owner or applicatnt
    end # End if current user isn't vote owner or applicatnt
  end # Second vote method



  private

  def set_vote
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end



  def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(
      :application_type,
      :application_id,
      :user_id,

      :accept,

      :modify,
      :modification,
      :suggest_loan,
      :describe_loan,

      :deny,
      :denial_fund_overuse,
      :denial_not_qualify,
      :denial_unreasonable_request,
      :denial_not_involved_charity,
      :denial_other,
      :denial_other_description,

      :superseded,
      :seconded
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: what happens if you remove some code? like.. only call `@vote.update` and nothing else, try removing everything you can to narrow it down. Also, show the whole controller, maybe something from above is not properly closed

Comment: @arieljuod If I just do `@vote.update` it calls `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'` on the `end` of the same method.

Comment: I think this ```flash[:warning]``` should be ```flash[:alert] ```

Comment: @Violeta I get the weird error even with the change.

Comment: Show the whole controller code. I bet the error happens even if you have an empty action, the problem comes from above. Also use a gem like rubocop to lint your files and it will find unclosed ruby blocks.

Comment: What does the view that calls this method look like?

Comment: @arieljuod The entire controller is added.  It's long, but I've tried to label everything as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a typo in `create` method of your controller

```
format.json { rend<%= @application.full_name %>er json: @vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

This causes interpretation issues